# I forgot the email i used to register on my Samsung S6 edge+ mobile

Tags: samsung, samsung-galaxy-s-6-edge+

I forgot the email i used to register on my Samsung S6 edge+ mobile, it does not allow to use the phone without entering the registered email, Is there any way to find the email account.

Comment: i don't think so. which account do you mean [Find My Mobile](https://findmymobile.samsung.com) / [Find My Device](https://www.google.com/android/devicemanager) ?

Comment: Do you additionally mean the SAMSUNG account? It is another way into a device, apart from the google account. They are sometimes linked.

Comment: Have you performed a factory reset before? If yes this is the [Factory Reset protection (FRP)](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/frp/info).

Answer (score 0):

Get the originall bill to prove your ownership , contact customer support with IMEI of your device and tell them your problem

Comment: and then? how can costumer support help?